# mysql Multiple left joins using count

Tags: mysql, join, count, coalesce

I have been researching this for hours and the best code that I have come up with is this from an example i found on overstack. I have been through several derivations but the following is the only query that returns the correct data, the problem is it takes over 139s (more than 2 minutes) to return only 30 rows of data. Im stuck. (life_p is a 'likes'

```
SELECT
  logos.id,
  logos.in_gallery,
  logos.active,
  logos.pubpriv,
  logos.logo_name,
  logos.logo_image,
  coalesce(cc.Count, 0) as CommentCount,
  coalesce(lc.Count, 0) as LikeCount
FROM logos

left outer join(
  select comments.logo_id, count( * ) as Count from comments group by comments.logo_id
) cc on cc.logo_id = logos.id

left outer join(
  select life_p.logo_id, count( * ) as Count from life_p group by life_p.logo_id
) lc on lc.logo_id = logos.id

WHERE logos.active = '1'
  AND logos.pubpriv = '0'
GROUP BY logos.id
ORDER BY logos.in_gallery desc
LIMIT 0, 30
```

I'm not sure whats wrong. If i do them singularly meaningremove the coalece and one of the joins:

```
SELECT
  logos.id,
  logos.in_gallery,
  logos.active,
  logos.pubpriv,
  logos.logo_name,
  logos.logo_image,
  count( * ) as lc
FROM logos

left join life_p on life_p.logo_id = logos.id

WHERE logos.active = '1'
  AND logos.pubpriv = '0'
GROUP BY logos.id
ORDER BY logos.in_gallery desc
LIMIT 0, 30
```

that runs in less than half a sec ( 2-300 ms )....

Here is a link to the explain: https://logopond.com/img/explain.png

Comment: by overstack i mean on here 'stackoverflow' :D, Thanks Jorge I was wondering how to fix the code display

Comment: Pls add the result of the explain and pls also list the indexes on the 3 affected tables!

Comment: Comments.logo_id, life_p.logo_id and logos.id are all indexed on their respective tables. Comments and logos table have several columns and some of them are indexed but not related to the request on the table.

heres a link to the explain https://logopond.com/img/explain.png

Comment: Pls edit the question and copy the explain there formatted for readability!

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a peculiar quirk that allows a group by clause that does not list all non-aggregating columns. This is NOT a good thing and you should always specify ALL non-aggregating columns in the group by clause.

Note, when counting over joined tables it is useful to know that the COUNT() function ignores NULLs, so for a LEFT JOIN where NULLs can occur don't use COUNT(*), instead use a column from within the joined table and only rows from that table will be counted. From these points I would suggest the following query structure.

```
SELECT
        logos.id
      , logos.in_gallery
      , logos.active
      , logos.pubpriv
      , logos.logo_name
      , logos.logo_image
      , COALESCE(COUNT(cc.logo_id), 0) AS CommentCount
      , COALESCE(COUNT(lc.logo_id), 0)   AS LikeCount
FROM logos
        LEFT OUTER JOIN comments cc ON cc.logo_id = logos.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN life_p lc ON lc.logo_id = logos.id
WHERE logos.active = '1'
AND logos.pubpriv = '0'
GROUP BY
        logos.id
      , logos.in_gallery
      , logos.active
      , logos.pubpriv
      , logos.logo_name
      , logos.logo_image
ORDER BY logos.in_gallery DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

If you continue to have performance issues then use a execution plan and consider adding indexes to suit.

Comment: this is closer to what i had when i started in terms of the left join but i didnt have the coalesce and the all the group bys, the issue with this is it ( takes less time 30 secs) makes the like and comment column contain the same number, I'll try to run it with distinct, but i was having no luck with that either.

Ultimately im just trying to avoid running a query inside a for loop as i loop through to get the logo info and other needed data from other tables.

Comment: `select distinct` would achieve absolutely nothing when used on that query (group by produces distinct rows already). The counts will only be the same if there happens to be the same number of rows in each joined table per group.

Comment: Yeah i just ran the query against the database and it gives the exact same info in both the comment count and like count  columns. i meant run the distinct within the count comments and count life_p

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT alias.column)` can produce a different number to `COUNT(alias.column)` - is this what you mean? But if you use the PK of the joined tables there should be no difference to final result. nb: I can't help further without visibility of the source data of the results that you are getting. also, I have no idea what query variant you are now running either.

Comment: not sure how to make this look readable in the comments; but basically the query as written returns CommentCount = 33 and LikeCount = 33, it should return CommentCount = 3 and LikeCount = 11. its doing that for all rows returned. so thats why i was running distinct on the count value but it simple returns both values as 1.

Comment: without access to data I can offer very little, all I can suggest is that your join conditions are not correct.

Comment: **EDIT** to query for aliases inside the count function calls.

Comment: thanks for your time @Used_by_already I ended up using a subquery, see below

Answer (score 1):

You can create some indexes on the joining fields:

ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `idx__tableName__fieldName` (`field`)

In your case will be something like:

ALTER TABLE cc ADD INDEX idx__cc__logo_id (logo_id);

Comment: I'll try this, didn't think it was necessary as the columns it was referencing were indexed, but obviously its not currently pulling efficientlly. I 'll let you know if that works

Comment: no go on this the index is already in the appropriate table and adding this only duplicates an index thats already there.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really like it because ive always read that sub queries are bad and that joins perform better under stress, but in this particular case subquery seems to be the only way to pull the correct data in under half a sec consistently. Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

```
SELECT 
    logos.id,
    logos.in_gallery,
    logos.active,
    logos.pubpriv,
    logos.logo_name,
    logos.logo_image,
(Select COUNT(comments.logo_id) FROM comments
    WHERE comments.logo_id = logos.id) AS coms,
(Select COUNT(life_p.logo_id) FROM life_p 
   WHERE life_p.logo_id = logos.id) AS floats 

FROM logos
WHERE logos.active = '1' AND logos.pubpriv = '0'
ORDER BY logos.in_gallery desc
LIMIT ". $start .",". $pageSize ."
```

Comment: do you need the group by clause in that query? as you are now using `correlated subqueries` there does not appear to be any reason for the group by

Comment: EDIT removed the group by, as it is unnecessary in this approach

Answer (score 0):

Also you can create a mapping tables to speed up your query try:

```
CREATE TABLE mapping_comments AS
SELECT
    comments.logo_id,
    count(*) AS Count
FROM
    comments
GROUP BY
    comments.logo_id
) cc ON cc.logo_id = logos.id
```

Then change your code

```
 left outer join(
```

should become

```
inner join mapping_comments as mp on mp.logo_id =cc.id
```

Then each time a new comment are added to the cc table you need to update your mapping table OR you can create a stored procedure to do it automatically when your cc table changes